# how to add scrollbar to dyanamically created controls in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, scrollbar

I want to know about using scroll bar for dynamically created control for wp7.I had tried many things but i don't know how to set scrollbar for controls that was created through codebehind

Comment: Create `ScrollViever` and place your content inside it. It can be done from code behind.

Comment: But i Want to add the scrollviewer to dynamically created buttons through looping,which throws invalid exception